# How to do aggregation query in MongoDB with date in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing my calls like this:

```
            let minDate = new Date(req.year, month, 1);
            let maxDate = new Date(req.year, month, 31);
```

then:

```
      const billings = await Billing.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        expiration: { "$gte": minDate, "$lte": maxDate },
                        deleted: false,
                        status: { $ne: "pago" }
                    },
                },
```

but it's not working. Is something wrong with date? Because when I take the `expiration` field off, it works.

Comment: `console.log()` the `minDate` and `maxDate` and make sure it's the correct date. Javascript counts months from 0

Comment: Please provide sample complete JSON collection documents